# Line height issues

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, fonts

I've got an issue with some text, I know it has something to do with the font itself but the font asks fine in Chrome but when in Firefox we get all these issues.

MOZILLA FIREFOX

[image: MOZILLA FIREFOX]

CHROME

[image: CHROME]

If I could get some help on this that would be great. A live version of this site is here: http://dev.dog-company.com/

EDIT: Also if you move your mouse over the text you will see the hover only working on the lower half of the text just as shown on the inspector.

Comment: looks like that's some kind of bug of the element inspector add-on used in Fire Fox, except that the Text is displayed OK in all the modern browsers.

Comment: No it's not. If you highlight the text you will see it not working. Also if you move your mouse over the text you will see the hover only working on the lower half of the text just as shown on the inspector.

Comment: I'm not sure what version of FireFox you're using but the latest version (I'm using) is OK, hovering is OK, highlighting is also OK, as I said, there is only one problem (looks like a bug) of the element inspector used in FireFox, normally selecting the `<a>` element in the DOM tree, the whole link should be highlighted in the page, however just the bottom half of the link is highlighted (like the first image posted in your question). All other browsers' element inspectors don't have such a problem.

Comment: I'm using Nightly and the problem was occurring on the Firefox too. The site now has a different font which has fixed the problem and why you cannot see it. Thanks for replying though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I was right.

The font type that firefox was using was broken. Just use another font if you run into this problem. Saves allot of time.

:)